# A closed set $F \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $F, F', F'', F''',\dots $ are all distinct

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $F \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a closed set. Let $F'$ be the set of the limit points of $F$.

Question: Does there exists a set $F$ such that $F, F', F'', F''', ..... $ are all distinct and nonempty?

I am having hard time trying to find such a set. I was thinking maybe the Cantor set, but I am unable to prove that Cantor set has such property.

Comment: **Note:**  $F'=F''=F'''=\ldots$

Comment: If **Cantor** or any other **closed set**, yes. $F=F'$ is not true in general?

Comment: Ok, $F'\subseteq F$?

Comment: Oh, I got confused. Notations! Didn't read the question properly.

Comment: I added details to my answer. Re the Cantor set, it is perfect, i.e. it is closed and has no isolated points. Hence all derived sets coincide with the Cantor set itself, and cannot be different.

Comment: Next you can do even more!  Define $F^{(\alpha)}$ for ordinals $\alpha$ like this. $F^{(0)}=F$, $F^{(\alpha+1)} = (F^{(\alpha)})'$ and for limit ordinal $\lambda$, let $F^{(\lambda)} = \bigcap_{\alpha < \lambda} F^{(\alpha)}$.  Now try to find sets $F$ with $F^{(\alpha)}$ all different up to some ordinal higher than $\omega$.  Say up to $\omega 2$.  Or up to $\omega^2$.  Or up to $\omega^\omega$.  Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You may take, for each $n$ a set $Y_n$ with $Y_n^{(n)}\not=\emptyset$, but $Y_n^{(n+1)}=\emptyset$, and you may think $Y_n\subset (n,n+1)$, and let $Y$ be the union of the $Y_n$.

For example if $S=\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N=1,2,..\}$ then $S'=\{0\}$, and $S''=\emptyset$.

If $T=\{\frac1n+\frac1{nm}:n,m\in\Bbb N\}$, then $T'=S$, $T''=\{0\}$, and $T'''=\emptyset$. This idea (adding more and more converging sequences) could be used to construct $Y_n$ as specified above. Note that $Y^{(n+1)}\not=Y^{(n)}$ since each time we compute the derivative, we get the empty set in one more interval. $\def\n{\Bbb N}$

Edit. Adding more detail. Also, changing some of the notation, for convenience and clarity, I hope the result would be a more consistent presentation (keeping the same idea as in the original answer). (Mainly, I prefer to use $\frac1{2^n}$ instead of $\frac1n$, in what follows. Some of the details would be difficult to verify if one works with $\frac1n$. Another alternative might be to use continued fractions, but I find 
$\frac1{2^n}$ most convenient. Also, $n$ was used above as an index with a different meaning in different context, so I change that to $i$ at some places, to avoid notational collision. So, I work with $Y_n$, but with $\frac1{2^i}$.)

Let $T_{-1}=\{0\}$ (i.e., singleton $0$) and $T_0=\cup\{\frac1{2^i}:i\in\n=1,2,..\}$. 
Let $Y_0=T_{-1}\cup T_0=\{0\}\cup\{\frac1{2^i}:i\in\n\}$. 
Note that $Y_0$ is closed, $Y_0'=\{0\}$, and $Y_0''=\emptyset$.

In the above, $T_0$ was ``obtained'' from $T_{-1}$ by taking a sequence converging down to the only element of $T_{-1}$.

Now, construct $T_1$ by taking, for each $t\in T_0$, a sequence converging down to $t$. More precisely, $T_1=\{\frac1{2^i}+\frac1{{2^i}{2^j}}:i,j\in\n\}$. 
Note that, for any fixed $i$, the sequence $\langle \frac1{2^i}+\frac1{{2^i}{2^j}} : j\in\n\rangle$ converges down to $\frac1{2^i}\in T_0$. 
Note also that said sequence $\langle \frac1{2^i}+\frac1{{2^i}{2^j}} : j\in\n\rangle$ is contained in the interval $(\frac1{2^i},\frac1{2^{i-1}})$ since 
$\frac1{2^i}+\frac1{{2^i}{2^j}} \le \frac1{2^i}+\frac1{{2^i}2} = 
\frac3{2^{i+1}} < \frac4{2^{i+1}} = \frac1{2^{i-1}}$. Thus, such sequences corresponding to different $i$ would be contained in disjoint intervals. 
(This is convenient if one tries to sketch or computer-generate a picture, and is helpful in verifying the properties claimed below. In particular, $T_0$, $T_1$, $T_2$, etc, defined below, will all be contained in $[0,1)$, and 
$Y_n\subset[n,n+1)$ for all $n$.)

The set $X=T_{-1}\cup T_0\cup T_1$ is closed and has the property that 
$X'=T_{-1}\cup T_0=Y_0=\{0\}\cup\{\frac1{2^i}:i\in\n\}$. Hence also $X''=Y_0'=\{0\}$ and $X'''=Y_0''=\emptyset$.

We also would want to ``disjontify" $X$ from $Y_0$. So, let 
$Y_1=(X+1)\subset[1,2)$ (where $X+1=\{x+1:x\in X\}$). 
One may verify that 
$\{1+\frac1{2^i}:i\in\n\}\subset Y_1'$, hence $1\in Y_1''$. Also, $Y_1''=\{1\}$, hence $Y_1'''=\emptyset$.

If $K=Y_0\cup Y_1$, then $K$ is closed, and $K''\not= K'''$ since 
$1\in K''\setminus K'''$. (Also, $K'''=\emptyset$.)

Let $T_2$ be obtained from $T_1$ by taking, for each $t\in T_1$, a sequence converging down to $t$. More precisely, $T_2=\{\frac1{2^i}+\frac1{{2^i}{2^j}}+\frac1{{2^i}{2^j}{2^k}}:i,j,k\in\n\}$. The set of limit points of $T_2$ contains $T_1$, by construction. Namely, for each fixed $i,j$, the sequence $\langle \frac1{2^i}+\frac1{{2^i}{2^j}}+\frac1{{2^i}{2^j}{2^k}}: k\in\n\rangle$ converges down to $\frac1{2^i}+\frac1{{2^i}{2^j}}\in T_2$. We have that $T_2'''=\{0\}$ and $T_2''''=\emptyset$. (Note that $T_1\subset T_2'$, and 
$\{\frac1{2^i}:i\in\n\}\subset T_1'\subset T_2''$.)

Let $Y_2=(2+(T_{-1}\cup T_0\cup T_1\cup T_2))\subset[2,3)$. 
Let $L=Y_0\cup Y_1\cup Y_2$, then $L$ is closed, and $L'''\not= L''''$ since 
$2\in L'''\setminus L''''$.

Proceeding as above (I hope the idea is clear ... it could be formalized further, using either more indices, or recursion), one could define a closed
$Y_n\subset[n,n+1)$ such that $Y_n^{(n+1)}=\{n\}$ and 
$Y_n^{(n+2)}=\emptyset$, where, in general, for any set $P$, by $P^{(n)}$ we denote the $n$-th derived set of $P$ defined recursively by $P^{(0)}=P$ and $P^{(n+1)}=(P^{(n)})'$. Well, one way to formalize would be as follows. 
First, $T_n=\{\frac1{2^{i_1}}+\frac1{{2^{i_1}}{2^{i_2}}}+\cdots+
\frac1{{2^{i_1}}{2^{i_2}}\cdots{2^{i_n}}}:i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n\in\n\}$. Then let 
$Y_n=(n+(T_{-1}\cup T_0\cup T_1\cup T_2\cup\dots\cup T_n))\subset[n,n+1)$.

Let $Y=\bigcup_{n\ge0} Y_n$. Then $Y$ is closed (since each $Y_n$ is closed and the family of the $Y_n$ is locally-finite), and all the $Y^{(n)}$ (i.e. derivatives, or derived sets, of all orders), all the $Y^{(n)}$ are distinct, since $n\in Y^{(n+1)}\setminus Y^{(n+2)}$. The latter, in turn, follows 
since $n\in Y_n^{(n+1)}\setminus Y_n^{(n+2)}$. I am tempted to add a picture 
(just points on the line, say $Y_0\cup Y_1$), I may try to sketch it, or perhaps 
you try it with paper and pencil (might be easier to do than with a computer).

As Bryan observed (thank you!) in his answer, I am describing an embedding of $\omega^{n+1}+1$ in $[n,n+1)$. I didn't think of it this way when I described it, but it is correct. (You probably need to know about ordinals and ordinal exponentiation to be able to correctly read the above, if you don't know, google it.)

Here is a picture of the set $K=Y_0\cup Y_1$. (To relate to Brian's picture, I have just used dots, on the real line, whereas Brian has replaced some dots with vertical line segments of varying length. I used dots of different colors, e.g. the red dots represent $1+T_1$.) Thank you for accepting my answer!

[image: set $K=Y_0\cup Y_1$]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This really is an addendum to Mirko Swirko's answer. I just thought a picture would be nice.

What I believe Mirko is describing is embedding the ordinal $\omega^{n+1}+1$ in the interval $[n, n+1)$ for $n=0, 1,\ldots$ with the 'top' element of the ordinal at the left-hand edge.

For example, the collection $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=2}^\infty$ represents the ordinal $\omega+1$ with the top element at $0$. The next ordinal $\omega^2+1$ that would be in the interval $[1, 2)$ is represented here:

$\hskip1in$ [image]

The dashed line at $2$ would be included in the ordinal $\omega^3+1$ in the interval $[2,3)$. We perform this pattern in each interval $[n,n+1)$. Each of these sets are closed since they contain their limit points. Also, although it is isn't true, in general, that the union of a countable collection of closed sets is closed, when the collection of closed sets is locally finite, as it is in this case, the union is closed as well.

Now the point of this construction is that when we move from $F$ to $F'$, then $F'$ is precisely the same as $F$ just shifted over the right one unit. And, in general, $F^{(n)}$ is the same as $F$ shifted to the right $n$ units. Thus we have a closed set $F$ such that $F^{(n)}$ is distinct from $F^{(m)}$ when $n\neq m$. (Actually, to make it *exactly* the same by shifting, we need to add an isolated point at $-1$ to the original $F$ I described, which causes no problem)